# How can I put the results in an array after use each in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, each

Hi I have this function:

```
changeTarea: function() {

    var self = this;
    $("#select_tarea_id").change(function() {
        var id_tarea = $("#select_tarea_id").val();

        $.each(self.objTareasFlot, function(index,value) {

            for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {

                if(value[i].Id == id_tarea) {

                    self.objTareasFlotFinal['id']=value[i].Id;
                    self.objTareasFlotFinal['id_pro']=value[i].Id_proyecto;
                    self.objTareasFlotFinal['tarea']=value[i].nombre_tarea;
                    self.objTareasFlotFinal['porcentaje']=value[i].porcentaje;

                    console.info(self.objTareasFlotFinal);
                }
            }
       });

    });
}
```

And the function print :

[image]

But I need the 3 results in one array

for example :

[image]

How can I do that with that function? Sorry for my english I did try to explain of the better way

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array and push populated object into it. Something like this:

```
changeTarea: function(){

var self = this;
var container[];

$("#select_tarea_id").change(function() {
    var id_tarea = $("#select_tarea_id").val();

$.each(self.objTareasFlot, function(index,value) {

    for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++){

        if(value[i].Id == id_tarea){

        self.objTareasFlotFinal['id']=value[i].Id;
        self.objTareasFlotFinal['id_pro']=value[i].Id_proyecto;
        self.objTareasFlotFinal['tarea']=value[i].nombre_tarea;
        self.objTareasFlotFinal['porcentaje']=value[i].porcentaje;

        console.info(self.objTareasFlotFinal);
        container.push(self.objTareasFlotFinal);
        }

    }


 });

});},
```

Comment: Hi , the function works when I change a option in a dropdown ( i get the id ) .. so when I change the option the "push" put more information that I need ..

Comment: Yes, actually the push func accepts more than one args. You can read more about here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: But i don't need push , i need replace each time , not add with a push

Answer (score 0):

Create an array variable `var result = [];` inside your function.

Within your loop [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the objects into it;

```
results.push(self.objTareasFlotFinal);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var newArray = [];

    self.objTareasFlotFinal['id']=value[i].Id;
                        self.objTareasFlotFinal['id_pro']=value[i].Id_proyecto;
                        self.objTareasFlotFinal['tarea']=value[i].nombre_tarea;
                        self.objTareasFlotFinal['porcentaje']=value[i].porcentaje;

    newArray.push(self.objTareasFlotFinal);

// console.log should show the results
console.log(newArray);
```

If this array is meant to be global and accessible outside the function, you might want to define newArray outside the function first and remove the var from it within the function.

Then every time somebody runs the function, a new object is added to the array.

Alternatively, you could just return the array as the final value:

```
     var newArray = [];

        self.objTareasFlotFinal['id']=value[i].Id;
                            self.objTareasFlotFinal['id_pro']=value[i].Id_proyecto;
                            self.objTareasFlotFinal['tarea']=value[i].nombre_tarea;
                            self.objTareasFlotFinal['porcentaje']=value[i].porcentaje;

        newArray.push(self.objTareasFlotFinal);

return newArray;
```